# KeyError when trying to blit image on to screen from Numpy array in Pygame

Tags: python, numpy, pygame

I've finished my chess game, but now I'm implementing a numpy array as the board so the chess AI I'm working on calculates faster. I know what a KeyError is, but I don't understand why its happening here.
Error:

```
line 86, in drawPieces
screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
KeyError: 9
```

My code:

```
import numpy
import pygame as p

p.init()
BOARD_WIDTH = 512
BOARD_HEIGHT = 512
DIMENSION = 8  # dimensions of a chess board are 8x8
SQ_SIZE = 512 // DIMENSION
MAX_FPS = 60  # for animations later on
screen = p.display.set_mode((BOARD_WIDTH, BOARD_HEIGHT))
IMAGES = {}

class GameState():
    def __init__(self):
        # board is 8x8 2D List, each element of the list has 2 characters
        # initial character == colour (b,w)
        # second character == piece
        # R == rook, N == knight, B == bishop, Q == Queen, K == king, P == pawn
        # -- == empty space
        board = [
            ["bR", "bN", "bB", "bQ", "bK", "bB", "bN", "bR"],
            ["bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp", "bp"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"],
            ["wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp", "wp"],
            ["wR", "wN", "wB", "wQ", "wK", "wB", "wN", "wR"]
        ]

        lookup = {
            "--": 0,
            "wK": 1, "wQ": 2, "wR": 3, "wB": 4, "wN": 5, "wp": 6,
            "bK": 7, "bQ": 8, "bR": 9, "bB": 10, "bN": 11, "bp": 12
        }
        self.board = numpy.array([[lookup[p] for p in row] for row in board])
        print(self.board)


def main():
    gs = GameState()
    clock = p.time.Clock()
    loadImages()  # only do this once, before the while loop
    running = True

    while running:

        for e in p.event.get():
            if e.type == p.QUIT:
                running = False

        drawGameState(screen, gs.board)

        clock.tick(MAX_FPS)
        p.display.update()

def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
# Note we can access an image by saying "IMAGES['wp']'


def drawGameState(screen, board):
    drawBoard(screen)  # draw squares on the board
    drawPieces(screen, board)


def drawBoard(screen):
    global colors
    colors = [p.Color("white"), p.Color("gray")]
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            color = colors[((r + c) % 2)]
            p.draw.rect(screen, color, p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != "--":  # not empty square
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code is only for displaying the board and pieces which is all I need to test. This is my first time running into `KeyError` cause I don't use dictionaries often. I'm getting all the values the dictionary needs. I've tried renaming the file to their dictionary number, didn't help. I don't know what to do. This is where you can get images to try it out yourself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chess_symbols_in_Unicode and rename the image for their counterpart. For instance white rook as `'wR'`, etc. If you need anymore information or anything let me know. I appreciate it.

Comment: Can you please show the complete error trace? In which line of code do you get the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`board` contains the numbers from 0 to 12, but the `IMAGES` dictionary uses the string keys "--", "bR", "bN". Hence, you cannot address the images in the `IMAGES` dictionary directly with the numbers stored in `board`:

Use the `lookup` table to create the `IAMGES` dictionary:

<s>`IMAGES[piece] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))`</s>

```py
IMAGES[lookup[piece]] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

Required changes:

```py
lookup = {
    "--": 0,
    "wK": 1, "wQ": 2, "wR": 3, "wB": 4, "wN": 5, "wp": 6,
    "bK": 7, "bQ": 8, "bR": 9, "bB": 10, "bN": 11, "bp": 12
}
```

```py
def loadImages():
    pieces = ['wp', 'wR', 'wN', 'wB', 'wK', 'wQ', 'bp', 'bR', 'bN', 'bB', 'bK', 'bQ']
    for piece in pieces:
        IMAGES[lookup[piece]] = p.transform.scale(p.image.load("images/" + piece + ".png"), (SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

```py
def drawPieces(screen, board):
    for r in range(DIMENSION):
        for c in range(DIMENSION):
            piece = board[r][c]
            if piece != 0:  # not empty square
                print(piece)
                screen.blit(IMAGES[piece], p.Rect(c * SQ_SIZE, r * SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE, SQ_SIZE))
```

Comment: Thanks you. I had: if piece != '0':

Comment: @Axhul The values stored in the numpy array are integral numbers